# How to retrieve an object name in JSON with jsonpath?

Tags: jsonpath, kettle

Using jsonpath with a JSON input in Pentaho Data Integration/Kettle I am trying and failing to retrieve the objects names:

```
{
  "otherobject":"dontcare",
  "objectid_01":{
    "property_01":"a",
    "property_02":["s","t"]
  },
  "objectid_02":{
    "property_01":"b",
    "property_02":["u","v"]
  }
}
```

I am able to extract `["a","b"]` with `$..property_01` but I would also need to get the names/ids/keys/whatever they are called `["objectid_01","objectid_02"]` with jsonpath.

Greatly appreciate your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
$.objectid_01.property_01
$.objectid_01.property_02
```

or

```
$.objectid_01.*.property_02
```

This syntax works in json input!

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Ana! However your first suggestion will only give me the values of the properties, ie `"a"` and `"b"`, but I am looking for finding the keys of the object with said properties, ie. `["objectid_01","objectid_02"]`. Sorry if this was unclear in my original post.The second line is not applicable to the JSON example provided I think.